# android:layout_marginLeft refer to the parent view or views around?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute, and I do not understand whether it will keep distance / margin to the parent or to the next view beside?

[Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_marginLeft) only says : `Specifies extra space on the left side of this view. This space is outside this view's bounds. Margin values should be positive.`.

Comment: If your View width is match_parent then it margin from the Parent View and if  View is beside the another View the it provide distance between 2 views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends on the parent layout.**

If it's `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `TableRow` then `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute will specifies extra space on the left side of one above child of the same parent view hierarchy (views around).

If it's `FrameLayout` then `android:layout_marginLeft` attribute will specifies extra space on the left side to its parent. It doesn't affect by other child of same parent.

Answer (score 0):

It will set the margin of that View within the parent LayoutGroup